# nothing is appearing in one of my views in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc

One of the views is not displaying anything; I don't know why.
It is supposed to automatically display a chart and the latest added 'TRSvalue' from a table in my db (based on the date that value was added) and keep updating every 5 seconds.
Here is the part of the controller that will get the chart and the latest value:

```
public IActionResult ShowData()
        {
            return View();
        }    
        [HttpPost]
        public List<object> GetData()
        {
            List<object> data = new List<object>();
            // Retrieve OEE values grouped by hour
            var oeeByHour = mvcDemoDbContext.Trss
                .GroupBy(p => new { p.Date.Year, p.Date.Month, p.Date.Day, p.Date.Hour })
                .Select(g => new {
                    Hour = $"{g.Key.Year}-{g.Key.Month.ToString("00")}-{g.Key.Day.ToString("00")} {g.Key.Hour.ToString("00")}:00:00",
                    AverageOee = g.Average(p => p.TRSValue)
                })
                .ToList();

            // Extract the hour labels and OEE values
            var labels = oeeByHour.Select(p => p.Hour).ToList();
            var values = oeeByHour.Select(p => p.AverageOee).ToList();

            data.Add(labels);
            data.Add(values);

            return data;
        }
      //""dashboard"
        public async Task<IActionResult> LatestTrsValue()
        {
            var latestTrs = await mvcDemoDbContext.Trss.OrderByDescending(t => t.Date).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            return View(latestTrs);

        }
```

And the view:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        GenerateChart(); // Call the function to generate the chart when the page loads
    });

    function GenerateChart() {
        var chartType = "line"; // Default chart type
       var chartView = document.getElementById('ChartView');
        chartView.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        $('#ChartView').append('<canvas id="myChart" style="max-width:750px;max-height:400px;"><canvas>');

       

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Trss/GetData",
            data: "",
            contextType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccessResult,
            error: OnError
        });

function OnSuccessResult(data) {

    var _data = data;
    var _chartLabels = _data[0].map(d => new Date(d).toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + new Date(d).toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }));;
    var _chartData = _data[1];

    var latestTRS = _chartData[_chartData.length - 1]; // get the latest TRS value

    $('#LatestTRS').text('Latest TRS value: ' + latestTRS); // display the latest TRS value

    var barColor = ["blue", "purple", "orange", "brown", "green", "red"];

    new Chart("myChart",                   //this is where we generate the graph
    {
            type: chartType,
            data: {
                labels: _chartLabels,
                datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor: barColor,
                    data: _chartData
                }]
            }
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({                                       //ajax method to fetch the data from the db
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Trss/GetData",
            data: "",
            contextType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                var _data = data;
                var _chartLabels = _data[0].map(d => new Date(d).toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + new Date(d).toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }));;
                var _chartData = _data[1];

                var latestTRS = _chartData[_chartData.length - 1]; // get the latest TRS value

                $('#LatestTRS').text('Latest TRS value: ' + latestTRS); // display the latest TRS value

                // update the chart with new data
                var chart = Chart.getChart("myChart");
                chart.data.labels = _chartLabels;
                chart.data.datasets[0].data = _chartData;
                chart.update();
            },
            error: OnError
        });
    }, 5000); // update every 5 seconds (adjust the interval as needed)

}

</script>
```

Comment: Have you set any breakpoints anywhere to confirm that code is getting executed as expected? Have you confirmed that data is received at the OnSuccessResult handler as an array of arrays? The setInterval handler doesn't seem to be doing as much data manipulation as the first part of OnSuccessResult.